# GWT Form input field does not have value

Tags: forms, gwt

I've got a weird problem with GWT and HTML forms.
I've made a simple FormPanel with 3 basic elements in it: FileUpload for image uploading, TextBox for the name of the image and Button for submit. Everything works (I can save the image server-side at least) except that whatever I type in the input field, it does not have a value, i.e. in Chrome's Inspect Element I clearly see that it has no value="..." field.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I can't save the name if it doesn't have any.
Edit:

```
private final FlowPanel imagePanel = new FlowPanel();
private final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
private final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
private final Button submitButton = new Button("Upload");
private final TextBox fileName = new TextBox();
private final HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
private final VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();

public void onModuleLoad()
{
    vp.add(fileUpload);
    hp.add(fileName);
    hp.add(submitButton);
    vp.add(hp);
    form.add(vp);

    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    form.setAction("/upload");

    fileUpload.setName("upload"); // image identifier, used in upload handler

    fileName.setName("fileName");
    fileName.setValue("Enter file name");
    fileName.setMaxLength(40);
    fileName.addStyleName("fileNameHint");

    RootPanel.get("uploadBar").add(form);
    RootPanel.get("thumbnails").add(imagePanel);
}
```

This is all of the layout except the event handlers. All that happens onSubmit is the fileUpload value is checked for allowed file extensions.

Answer (score 1):

On the same note, the root cause of my problem was that I called form.reset() too soon. Note that very input field will be the target of form.submit() and form.reset(). So your TextBox will be also sent as form.submit() and if you call reset it'll get wiped out.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute defines the  `defaultValue` property of the node. Setting the `value` property (programmatically or *interactively* in the control) doesn't change the element's attributes.

If you want to see the element's current value in Chrome's Developer Tools, select it in the "Elements" pane (it's already selected if you use the "Inspect element" context menu item) and type `$0.value` in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Ok, so I can view the value in the Dev Tools, but how do I make that value appear on form submit? Currently it's NULL and I have no idea why is that so because input.getValue() in form.onSubmit() returns the correct value but on server side it gives me NULL.

Comment: Oh sorry, you said that "everything works", so I thought you only had an issue with the Dev Tools. Make sure you `setName` on your `TextBox`, and of course that it's within the `FormPanel`. It could help if you show your code that builds the UI.

Comment: You will have to parse the POST request to get the parameters and you will not be able to do so by using request.getParameter... type of functions. Generally a 3rd party library is used to achieve the parsing e.g.
Jakarta fileupload : http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/fileupload/

Comment: *final List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);* looping through this, *if (item.getFieldName().equals("fileName"))* - *item.getName() == null*. I also tried just printing out each of the items with *response.getWriter()* and *Window.alert*'ing it all in the end, and the value of *fileName* is always NULL, there is never the actual typed value anywhere.

Comment: It's also the same if I use GWTUpload and add the input field to the SimpleFileUploader Widget.